# Replace Entity Framework object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In MVC app, I am having this big object that is used in classic view/edit/create pattern.

When user edits the object I save it as:

```
  public bool SetMyObject(MyObject newObject) {
     MyObject current = GetObjectById(newObject.Id);
     current.Prop1 = newObject.Prop1
     ...
     current.PropN = newObject.PropN
     db.SaveChanges();
  }
```

MyObject is pretty big so I am wondering is there any better way to do this, not involving per-property assignments. For instance something along the lines `db.MyObject.UpdateObject(current, tnew)`.

Ty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`ApplyPropertyChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.applypropertychanges.aspx) method.

> Applies property changes from a detached object to an object already attached to the object context.

```
public bool SetMyObject(MyObject newObject)
{
    db.ApplyPropertyChanges("MyObjectSet", newObject);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

(where "MyObjectSet" is the name of the entity set to which the object belongs)